# Keycloak user federation issue with email constraint

Tags: keycloak

I am checking Keycloak user federation with openldap source. It worked fine & synced users but some users are not synced as they have the same email id as already synced users.
I see this constraint in Keycloak postgresql user_entity table:
CONSTRAINT uk_dykn684sl8up1crfei6eckhd7 UNIQUE (realm_id, email_constraint)

But we need only uid (userName in Keycloak) unique. Is there anyway to configure that email can be duplicated?

Comment: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/3630

Comment: But this issue still in latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the 'duplicateEmailsAllowed' parameter is not considered if you do a partial import but only if you create the realm. I think it's right this way, being that field a configuration of the realm